# Options for gpg1 instead of gpg2 on CentOS/RHEL 6?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, gpg

I have a customer whose application workflow relies on gnupg (gpg). Their system was recently migrated from CentOS 5.x, which shipped with gnupg version 1, to CentOS 6.5, which has gnupg version 2.

While this change should have been noticed in the testing stages, it was missed by the developers, and the application is now broken.

Are there any options to run the older variant of gnupg on an EL6 system? There doesn't seem to be an obvious solution, so how can I get back to the previous version's functionality?

The nature of the issue seems to surround the gpg2 requirement of an agent. From the man page ;)

> ```
>    --no-use-agent
>           This is dummy option. gpg2 always requires the agent.
> ```

The relevant command string is:

`# cat /home/db1/.passphrase | gpg --no-tty --passphrase-fd 0 --output xxx.TXT --decrypt xxx.pgp`

The response is:

> can't connect to `/home/jsmith/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent': No such file or
>   directory

With a helping of:

> pinentry-curses: no LC_CTYPE known - assuming UTF-8

Comment: `mkfifo /home/jsmith/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent` ?

Comment: I tried to experiment with the agent... but seeing as this is sprinkled throughout the application (and likely hardcoded), the path of least resistance is to probably get things back to their original working state.

Comment: I have no idea. It just works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still install the **gnupg** (v1) package in Fedora, so it might be available in CentOS as well. You can have both gnupg and gnupg2 installed at the same time in Fedora.

Alternatively, to get gpg2 to work how you expect (i.e., for the `--passphrase*` options to actually do anything) you need to use the `--batch` option.

Comment: Thanks... I went down this path and installed a specific gpg1 package.

Comment: Where did you find this gpg1 package?

Comment: @cjm in Fedora the old gpg1 rpm is called `gnupg` and the newer one is called `gnupg2`, but really, there's virtually no reason to be using gpg1 now on a new install.

Comment: @rsaw, I'm looking for a CentOS 6 package.  It only seems to have `gnupg2`.  The reason is I'm using gpg to do symmetric encryption with a passphrase, have no use for the agent, and I'm tired of seeing this warning message.

Comment: @cjm Create a new question and ping it to me.